# Implement Realm Design for Tags

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

I know Realm is NoSQL and doesn't support join operations. Currently, I have MySQL database having tables like this -

```
Table: Data
Columns: DataID, Title

Table: Tag
Columns: TagID, Title

Table: DataTag
Columns: DataID, TagID
```

How can I implement a Realm Model for this type table structure?

Comment: I use Realm with Swift, but ... Isn't this covered by https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#many-to-many? With Realm you don't need the equivalent of the join table, `DataTag`, you would instead have a property on `Data` that is a `RealmList<Tag>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Data extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    String dataId;

    String title;

    RealmList<Tag> tags;

    //get,set
}

public class Tag extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    String tagId;

    String title;

    RealmList<Data> datas;

    // get, set
}
```

Setting up relations is manual.

Comment: But won't it create duplication because Each multiple data has same tags and in `Tag` class different tags have same data value

Comment: I thought you had your primary key for a reason